# how to safely update php 7.2.24 to 7.2.33 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, php

I have a production environment and at this point I want to keep php 7.2 but would like to update to the latest 7.2.X version

What is the safest way to do the upgrade?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This PPA - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php` - seems to be well maintained, includes updates for php versions 7.0 through 7.4.